# How to find who created a SQL Server in Azure Portal?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azureportal

How to find who created a SQL Server in Azure Portal? I need to know the createdUserId of that particular SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information from the [Activity Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-log-collect) which has information about the created user and so on.

Comment: But it is showing upto 90 days only in the custom option. This SQL Server is created before 90 days.

Comment: You can't. The only way to keep logs for longer than 90 days is to archive them to a storage account